# Spring CORS settings

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cors, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to enable the cross origin header to be able to reach the service from anywhere (only on local env) but I cannot.

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CrossOriginConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final SecurityConfiguration securityConfiguration;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) { 
    registry.addMapping("*").allowedOrigins(securityConfiguration.getCrossOrginFilter());
    }
}
```

I made a custom index.html with an ajax call and it fails due to the Allow-Cross-Origin header missing and it comes from another origin.

Simple Spring Boot 2.0 controllers are used with @RestController annotation and simple @GetMapping.

What I missed? What should I include and where?

Comment: use `@crossorigin` in your controller.

Comment: I added it to the controller itself and also tried to add it explicitly for the GetMapping but still nothing.

Comment: Are you using `spring-security` as well?

Comment: Looks like it should be implemented, see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-cors
Have you tried "/**" as argument in the "addMapping" method? What value is passed to "allowedOrigins" with your security configuration? Is that exactly the origin that your "index.html" is hosted at?

Comment: Georg Wittberger got the point. Thank you, I'll write the answer based on that comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Georg Wittberger pointed out the problem was with the mapping. I used the * wildcard what is not good for paths.

Instead of this: registry.addMapping("*")

I used this: registry.addMapping("/**") and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the below annotation on either on the controller class or the specific method:

**@CrossOrigin**

By default, its allows all origins, all headers, the HTTP methods specified in the @RequestMapping annotation and a maxAge of 30 minutes is used.

If you want to allow only http://localhost:8080 to send cross-origin requests

**@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")**

Replace the host and port accordingly.

Check the below Spring documentation for more information:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/